# Resampling converts int to float, but only in group by

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a large dataframe. In order to save memory, I want to work with integers (int32) rather than floats.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start='2016-01-01', periods=4, freq='W'),
               'group': [1, 1, 2, 2],
               'val': [5, 6, 7, 8]})
df['val'] = df['val'].astype(np.int32)
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

df['val'].dtype
#[out] dtype('int32')
```

Calling resample() on the dataframe does not change the type.

```
df1 = df.resample('1D', fill_method='ffill')
df1['val'].dtype
#[out] dtype('int32')
```

However, when calling resample() in a group by statement, float type is returned!

```
df2 = df.groupby('group').resample('1D', fill_method='ffill')
df2['val'].dtype
#[out] dtype('float64')
```

Why is `val` converted to float in the group by statement? And how can I avoid this conversion in order to save memory? I'm using Pandas 17.1 and Numpy 1.10.1.

Comment: this maybe a bug, can you post this as an issue on [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues)

Comment: It's indeed a bug and will be fixed in 0.18. https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12202